# Cannot load ruby gems in irb

Tags: rvm, global, gemset

I'm pretty sure I screwed this up the other day attempting to create an individual gemset for a specific application, because everything was ok until I did that. But I believe it took place upon an rvm @gloabl gemset create I ran.

I'm honestly not sure which direction to go in order to rectify it, but any suggestions would be AWESOME.

But here is what I'm getting when I attempt to install a gem in irb via (require 'ap'), which was working as of a few days ago.

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- ap
    from /Users/Construct/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/Construct/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/Construct/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to run `require 'rubygems'` first?

Comment: I did attempt this although it returns me a "false", when using irb.

Comment: It's normal behaviour. So, you get LoadError even after "require 'rubygems'"?